React Native Ionicons not working and there is no any folder named @expo/vector-icons
I am newly learning React Native and I have a problem with Ionicons icons, it is not working.
I created project yesterday and searched + tried a lot of solutions 2 days, but none of them worked.
So, I need any help comment etc.
I have tried some github page solutions

I don't really have enough information. What do you mean by "not working." Does the IDE give an error or does the app itself give the error? Something you could try are: killing the IDE and restarting, clearing your npm cache, or deleting node_modules and reinstalling.

I mean it is not showing related icons and when I searched the folder @expo/vector-icons there is no any folder with that name.

What does your package.json file look like?

Did you delete node_modules, restart your IDE, and redownload node_modules?
